# Click function getting old data attribute value - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a standard click function in jQuery,

```
$( ".related-play" ).click(function() {
  $('#playlist .panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
  track_id = $('.related-play').data('id');
  $('#collapse-' + track_id).addClass("in");
  $('#collapse-' + track_id + " li").removeClass("active");
  $('#collapse-' + track_id + " .related").addClass("active");c
  console.log(track_id);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="collapse-1156” class="panel-collapse collapse”>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs inside-track-tabs">
           <li class=“active stems"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#stems-1156">Stems</a></li>
           <li class="related"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#related-1156">Related Tracks</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content inside-track-content”>
    <div id=“stems-1156" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
    <div id="related-1156" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
</div>

<a class="related-play" data-id="1156">RELATED</a>
```

Separate to this function I also have another function that alters the data-id attribute based off other events in the page, via the use of this jQuery line

```
trackID = 1567 (This is just an example but actually trackID is generated at random and could be any number of different IDs
)
jQuery(".related-play").attr("data-id", trackID);
```

For some reason, I click related-play once, and it grabs it fine for the first time, however when I click it again, after the data attribute has changed and it grabs the old value. I check the DOM and this data attribute has an updated value, its getting the old value.

I can't see why it would do this though

Comment: Could you please include your html code or create a snippet with the problem.

Comment: also try this `track_id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: Updated @CarstenLøvboAndersen, that collapse div is an example of one of many with all different track_id's

Comment: without you make a snippet that show us exactly the problem i fear it might be hard for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

**In jQuery, `$(this)` is used to refer to the current object**

You need to give current reference object using `this` as below

```
$( ".related-play" ).click(function() {
  $('#playlist .panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
  track_id = $(this).data('id'); // Change applied
  $('#collapse-' + track_id).addClass("in");
  $('#collapse-' + track_id + " li").removeClass("active");
  $('#collapse-' + track_id + " .related").addClass("active");c
  console.log(track_id);
});
```

Comment: @DIM3NSION - use `$(this)` to get current object data-id

Comment: Thanks!, I've changed it to this, but it just grabs the old data attribute value thats not in the DOM anymore

Comment: @Mantas Čekanauskas Your fiddle works because you are using two seperate buttons with the same data-attribute. He is setting the attribute in a single button with another function.

Comment: @DIM3NSION I just had the same exact problem. I changed $(this).data('id') to $(this).attr('data-id') and it got the most recent value. Don't ask me why but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly working for me.

```
 track_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```